# How to select query from json in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

I have JSON data in field `hotel_data` like this:

```
{ 
   "title":"foo",
   "description":[ 
      { 
         "locale":"pt",
         "content":"pt text"
      },
      { 
         "locale":"fr",
         "content":"fr text"
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to select `description` only `fr` description. It is possible using Postgres and how?

I was trying use `->>` but it is not working...

```
SELECT  
    hotel_data->'description'->>'locale' = 'fr' AS description
FROM hotel LIMIT 1;
```

Note:
I don't want to use `SELECT *`...

Excepted output: `{description: "fr text"}`

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join and `json_to_recordset` to expand the json array as a set of records. Then, you can filter on column `locale` in the generated records, and finally recompose a new json object with your expected result:

```
select json_build_object('description', d.content) hotel_data_descr_fr
from 
    mytable,
    json_to_recordset(hotel_data->'description') as d("locale" text, "content" text)
where d.locale = 'fr'
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=eaecaf9b545eb06b1c8398ba053dfe06)**:

```
with mytable as (
    select '{ 
   "title":"foo",
   "description":[ 
      { 
         "locale":"pt",
         "content":"pt text"
      },
      { 
         "locale":"fr",
         "content":"fr text"
      }
   ]
}'::json hotel_data
)
select json_build_object('description', d.content) hotel_data_descr_fr
from 
    mytable,
    json_to_recordset(hotel_data->'description') as d("locale" text, "content" text)
where d.locale = 'fr'
```

```
| hotel_data_descr_fr        |
| :------------------------- |
| {"description": "fr text"} |
```

Comment: Sound good like correct working solution, but seems to be suicide when I need to filter more values like "description", "headline", "body", ...

Comment: @jimodefax: well, you did not state that it had to be generic... But this probably doable with json_each and the same overall logic.

Comment: @jimodefax You mean you've got multiple fields in that format of by-locale json arrays? You can `JOIN` them by their `locale` fields then, or even do it generically for all fields in your object with `json_each` like GMB suggested. But please [ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about that

Answer (score 1):

The filtering can be done using the `@>` operator which can use a GIN index on the `hotel_data` column. This is typically faster than expanding the array.

```
select ...
from hotel
where hotel_data @> '{"description": [{"locale":"fr"}] }';
```

This can also be extended to include more properties:

```
select ...
from hotel
where hotel_data @> '{"description": [{"locale":"fr", "headline": "nice view'}] }';
```

But you can only express equality conditions on the key/value pairs with that. Using `LIKE` is not possible. You will have to expand the array if you want to do that and apply the condition in the WHERE clause - see GMB's answer.

To extract that description, I would use a scalar sub-query:

```
select (select jsonb_build_object('description', t.descr ->> 'content')
        from jsonb_array_elements(h.hotel_data -> 'description') as t(descr)
        where t.descr ->> 'locale' = 'fr'
        limit 1)
from hotel h
where h.hotel_data @> '{"description": [{"locale":"fr"}] }';
```

That way you don't need to expand the array for filtering which I expect to be faster if only a few hotels qualify for that condition. But it has the drawback that you need to repeat the condition on the locale in the sub-select.

The limit 1 is only a safety net in case you have more than one french description. If you never have that, it doesn't hurt either

---

With Postgres 12 this is easier:

```
select jsonb_build_object(
         'description', 
         jsonb_path_query_first(hotel_data, '$.description ? (@.locale == "fr")') -> 'content'
       )
from hotel
where hotel_data @> '{"description": [{"locale":"fr"}] }'
```

---

All of the above assumes `hotel_data` is a `jsonb` column, if it's not (which it should be) you need to cast it: `hotel_data::jsonb`

Comment: Could you not even put another `.content` in the JSON path instead of using `->`?

Comment: Yes, that would also be possible `jsonb_path_query_first(hotel_data, '$.description ? (@.locale == "fr").content')`